# About using ASP.NET security and Membership in web applications

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-membership

I have 3 questions about using ASP.NET security and Membership in web applications

1. Do people outside localhost have any means of accessing the ASP.NET security control panel?

   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmYwQ.jpg]
2. What is the best way to edit security? Is it by opening the website through VS2010 and editing security, or there is another way or some control panel I can use?
3. I can't edit security while the folder is in wwwroot, so I have to cut it into desktop, edit its security the put it back in wwwroot folder. I don't think this is an acceptable way at all, any better ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Web Site Administration Tool (WSAT) is the default means to manage a ASP.NET site out of the box.  If you want a deployable solution that can be integrated into your website you should look at the [MyWSAT](http://mywsat.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex.  It provides all the features of WSAT.

Answer (score 3):

1: No you cannot access the WSAT tool outside of localhost and it has to be used in conjunction with VS. (Note: I have seen people trying that but somehow it isn't easy.

2: You can use modules already created by others as one mentioned by Zack. [Similar one is here.](https://web.archive.org/web/20210306174425/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx) Or you can use [Membership/Roles API](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/security) to write your own pages do this work.

3: Not sure what is going on with your wwwroot issue. May be it could be some permission issue. Are you getting any error?